# I am using antd deign to show select option but select cant read id provided and also cannot update onChange

Tags: react-hooks, antd, react-context

I am using antd deign to show select option but select cant read id provided and also cannot update onChange.

```
import React from "react";


const data = {
  orgName: "",
  orgRegNo: "",
  orgType: "",

  orgTypes: [
    { id: "1", name: "Vendor" },
    { id: "2", name: "Supplier" },
    { id: "3", name: "Vendor and Supplier" }
  ]
};



export const MyContextTSX = React.createContext(data);

const Store = (props: any) => {
  return (
    <MyContextTSX.Provider value={data}>{props.children}</MyContextTSX.Provider>
  );
};

export default Store;
```

//Next page of React signup

```
const signinData = useContext(MyContextTSX);


const [values, setValues] = useState(signinData);

<Select
                  id={values.orgTypes.id}  //shows error while showing id
                  // name={values.orgTypes.name}
                  defaultValue="Choose"
                  style={{ width: 150 }}
                  onChange={(value: any) => //cant perform onChange
                    setValues({ ...value, name: value })
                  }
                >
                  {values.orgTypes.map((option: any) => (
                    <Option
                      key={option.id}
                      value={option.name}
                      // onChange={handleChange}
                    >
                      {option.name}
                    </Option>
                  ))}
                </Select>
```

I am using antd deign to show select option but select cant read id provided and also cannot update onChange.

[Link to CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-48zl9)

Comment: Try to reproduce your problem in codesandbox.io. While doing so you will figure out the problem. If not, post the link to it here;-)

Comment: Dont post part of codes, post you entire `Signup` component

Comment: can u look into it here ? I have updated full code

Comment: No, it's an invalid component, post the entire code.

Comment: I have imported it to codesandbox can u please look into it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues in your code.

**Firstly**, you are trying to access `id` from `orgTypes` which is an array. Instead you can defined a normal id.

**Secondly**, You need to have a contextProvider wrapping your App component

**Third**. You need to update state in the correct format such that you are not updating the data but the selected value. For that you need to have a state for selected value

Relavant code

index.js

```
ReactDOM(
  <Store>
    <App />
  </Store>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

useForm.js

```
import { useContext, useState } from "react";

import { MyContextTSX } from "./Store";

const useForm = ({ callback }) => {
  const values = useContext(MyContextTSX);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState({});

  return { values, selected, setSelected };
};

export default useForm;
```

Register.js

```
const Register = () => {
  const { values, selected, setSelected } = useForm({});
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Select
        id={"select"} //shows error here
        defaultValue="Choose"
        style={{ width: 150 }}
        onChange={(
          value: any //what to do here ?
        ) => setSelected(selected)} //what to do here ?
      >
        {values.orgTypes.map((option: any) => (
          <Option key={option.id} value={option.name}>
            {option.name}
          </Option>
        ))}
      </Select>
      <button onClick={() => console.log(values.orgTypes)}>Test</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

[image: eact-typescript-mvq21]

Comment: are you from nepal ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with your code:

```js
id={values.orgTypes.id} // orgTypes is an array, use values.orgTypes[0].id

---

onChange={(
  value: any // value is the Select.Option value
  ) => setValues({ ...value, name: value })} // What exatcly you trying to do here?
```

Moreover, you don't specify types (and using `Typescript`).

Check this working example (`Javascript`):

```js
const data = {
  orgName: '',
  orgRegNo: '',
  orgType: '',

  orgTypes: [
    { id: '1', name: 'Vendor' },
    { id: '2', name: 'Supplier' },
    { id: '3', name: 'Vendor and Supplier' }
  ]
};

const MyContextTSX = React.createContext(data);
function Signup() {
  const signinData = useContext(MyContextTSX);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Selected: {selected}</h1>
      <Select
        defaultValue="Choose"
        style={{ width: 150 }}
        onChange={value => setSelected(value)}
      >
        {signinData.orgTypes.map(option => (
          <Select.Option key={option.id} value={option.name}>
            {option.name}
          </Select.Option>
        ))}
      </Select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Demo:

[image: Edit magical-frog-gm12y]

Comment: thanks alot, I m starting to learn so please bear with me, can u pleas upvote this question, I cant post questions

Comment: Yes, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking, before posting another question, poor quality questions are downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Tweaking little bit @Dennish Vash answer and the signup function can also be written like this

```
function Signup() {
  const signinData = useContext(MyContextTSX);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Selected: {selected}</h1>
      <Select
        defaultValue="Choose"
        style={{ width: 150 }}
        onChange={value => setSelected(value)}
      >
        {signinData.orgTypes.map(option => (
        <Option value="{option.id}">{option.name}</Option>
  
        ))}
      </Select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Reference: https://github.dev/ant-design/ant-design/tree/master/components/select/demo